# SoapUI build on Windows server TFS

Tags: deployment, tfs, soapui

I'm about to deploy a soapui project that is made in the soapui PRO version. Must i have soapui PRO installed on the build server which rund TFS to be able to run the tests?

Comment: What is the reason to use different tools one to build and another one for execution? By the way, if the project uses pro steps, do you expect non-pro software to execute them?

Comment: so i must have soapui PRO installed on the tfs to execute the tests?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no [TFS integrated with SoapUI](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4187291-soapui-integrated-with-tfs), you may need to install the SoapUI on your build server.

You can call your test using a bat file, add this bat file to your source control so that it is carried accross with the build.Then Add an invoke process to your build template and then call out to the SoapUI test runner.

Here is a bolg telling you how to include SoapUI in your CI build cycle:http://blog.simplecode.eu/post/Soap-UI-testing-with-MsTest